# Difficulty in Proving $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}\ge \prod_{k=1}^{n}a_k.\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{a_k}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis

For $ 0<a_k\le1$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}\ge \prod_{k=1}^{n}a_k.\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{a_k}$$
 I tried by induction but   it becomes complicated.  then I tried $\text{A.M} \ge\text{ G.M}\ge\text{ H.M} $  but worth nothing. Please help if you can.

Comment: Sorry I forget to write condition $0<a_k\le1$

Comment: Can't we simply sum $n$ inequalities like $a_1\leq a_1a_2\ldots a_{n-1}$?

Answer (score 5):

The question has been edited.

The inequality is false. Take $a=c=1$ and $b=10$ for example.

Answer for the new version:

You can write RHS as $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \prod_{i \neq k} a_i$. Now $\prod_{i \neq k} a_i \leq a_{k+1}$ where $a_{n+1}$ is interpreted as $a_1$. This gives RHS $ \leq \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_k$.

Comment: Have you considered the edit made by OP?

Comment: @Manan See my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Apply AM-GM inequality to each product of the sum of the right hand side ( $RHS$ ):
$RHS \le \dfrac{(n-1)(a_1^{n-1}+a_2^{n-1}+...+a_n^{n-1})}{n-1}= a_1^{n-1}+a_2^{n-1}+...+a_n^{n-1} \le LHS$ because $a_k^{n-1} \le a_k$ for each $k$ as $0 < a_k \le 1$.